# Upper bound for the sum of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ be a set of positive numbers and $\epsilon > 0$ such that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{X_i}} \geq \epsilon$$
Is it possible to find an upper bound such that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_i} \leq f(\epsilon)$$
where $f$ is a smooth function.

Comment: No. If you choose $X_1 = 1/\epsilon$ then $X_2, X_3, ...$ can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 0):

No. For a given $\epsilon > 0$ you can choose $X_1 = 1/\epsilon$ and
arbitrary positive $X_2, X_3, ...$. Then 
$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{X_i}} \geq \epsilon$ is satisfied
and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_i}$  can be arbitrarily large.

Note that the inequality between the harmonic and the arithmetic mean
provides an estimate in the *opposite* direction:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{X_i}} < \varepsilon \Longrightarrow
\sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_i} > \frac{N^2}{\varepsilon}
$$